# How to handle gitpython clone exceptions?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I'm trying to write a batch clone script with GitPython, however I can't find a valid example of hanlding such as git url not exsits, download interupt etc.

How could I actually do this？

my exsiting code:

```
giturl = 'https://github.com/'+username+'/'+hwName+'.git'
targeturl = os.path.join(hwfolder,username+'-'+hwName)
try:
    repo = Repo.clone_from(giturl, targeturl, branch='master')
except:
    #git url not reachable
    #download interupt
    #target local path problem
```

Comment: Gitpython has a list of custom exceptions [here](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference.html#module-git.exc)

Comment: But clearly the exceptions there cannot cover all the situations.

Comment: GitPython appears to run the git binary for many operations, including clone.  If so, clone failure will be represented as a generic command failure.  (Interrupt is simply `KeyboardInterrupt` of course.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[For starters](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.exc.GitError),

> `exception git.exc.GitError`
>
> Base class for all package exceptions

Then, who said you *have* to handle all, or *any* exceptions? You can only reasonably handle those that you can do something intelligent about. The underlying `git` and the TCP stack are already smart enough to handle transient problems like an unreliable connection, so if it failed, you can't, as a rule, just try again and hope it happens to work this time.

For the purpose of a batch job, just propagate the error upstream so that your script fails gracefully. E.g. in a `.bat` file, you need to write something like `<command> || exit 1` for the script to terminate upon error rather than continue blindly.

---

Now, of your 3 specific cases:

- items 1 and 2 will probably make an underlying `git` fail, [all of those cases yield `GitCommandError`](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/master/git/cmd.py#L292)
- [`NoSuchPathError` is only ever raised](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/cf8dc259fcc9c1397ea67cec3a6a4cb5816e3e68/git/repo/base.py#L126) on `Repo` initialization if the path to the local repo doesn't exist